# Comparison "as" or "like"

Tags: comparison, as-like

I came through a question that is given below

In comparison, We use "like" for noun and noun phrase and "as" for preposition phrase and clause that has a verb. So the word "as" is followed by "bacon," which is a noun. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**Incorrect:** Many are confused that the Atkins Diet, which permits such seemingly less healthy foods ***like*** bacon, forbids bread.

**Correct:** Many are confused that the Atkins Diet, which permits such seemingly less healthy foods ***as*** bacon, forbids bread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both **as** and **like** can be used as a preposition or a conjunction. In this sentence, we need a preposition because it is followed by the noun **bacon**.

[As or like](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-or-like) - . The prepositions as and like have different meanings. As + noun means ‘in the role of’, like + noun means ‘similar to’ or ‘in the same way as’.

In your example, we need a word that means 'similar to', so **like** is the correct choice:

> Many are confused that the Atkins Diet, which permits such seemingly less healthy foods **like** bacon, forbids bread.

Alternatively, we can use **such as** which also means "similar to'.

> Many are confused that the Atkins Diet, which permits such seemingly less healthy foods **such as** bacon, forbids bread

Comment: So you are saying that the "incorrect" is correct

Comment: Yes, the one that you marked as incorrect is actually correct. It seems to be correct according to your rule too, because bacon is a noun.

Comment: It is a question from GMAT sentence correction. They usually provide correct solution. So I thought they may have a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

GMAT is indeed correct, but it is not a simple use of *as*. It's a split form of *such as*. Note that JavaLatte's second version uses *such* twice.
In other words, "...which permits **such** less healthy foods **as** bacon..." is correct and has the same meaning as "...which permits less healthy foods **such as** bacon..."